# Problem with a locked question

Tags: discussion, questions, locked

I am experiencing a problem with this link:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I see the question like this:

[image: What!]

As you can see, the text is going mad in the answer, which I think it is meant to, and the locked / reason text isn't in the right place, as you can see highlighted.

Is this a bug? And yes, I have refreshed without the cache.

Comment: Why don't you think the text isn't in the right place? It's a locked answer to a locked question (ok, so the text says "question" and that might be a bug).

Comment: It displays exactly the same way in Chrome 16.

Comment: That because the answer is locked, not the question.

Comment: @Mat -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117521/155556

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "locked by" text is correctly placed, as it is referring to the answer; the reason for doing that is that locking a question doesn't stop its answers from being editable or voted, while in this case it's the answer that needs to be locked (to avoid it is voted, or edited).

[image: screenshot]

If the answer were not locked, it would appear as the following one (the one after that):

[image: screenshot]

The "This question exists because it […]" is also referred to the answer, even if the text says *question*. When a moderator locks a post, it can choose a message that shows why the post has been locked; I guess the one you see is the default one, or the one chosen by the moderator when he locked the answer.

As for the lock message appearing under the comments, it seems to be fixed now, as I see with an answer of mine.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what about the locked message in the wrong place?

Comment: @HBellamy it is not in the wrong place. **Just** the answer is locked, **not** the question

Comment: @justcool393 It seems it has been fixed; see my update.